# Docker DNS resolution slow from host machine

Tags: java, docker, dns, ignite

Running Docker 18.03 on RedHat 7.5, I'm having an issue where DNS resolution from host machine to containers is taking 15-20 seconds. All other DNS queries (including inside containers) is fine.

Our setup is an Apache Ignite cluster that runs inside a container, and on the host machine we run a Java application that connects to the cluster. During initialization, we see a delay of around a minute before the app is connected to Ignite. Several jstacks and investigation of the Ignite code show it is doing a IP -> hostname resolution for a bunch of IPs when it first connects to the Ignite cluster.

I wrote a quick test that emulates what the host machine app is doing when trying to connect to the Ignite cluster:

https://gist.github.com/michael-pratt/a27b10c81b35ada3a4619eb48cad9ae5

The app calls `InetAddress.getHostName()` for all non link local addresses for all network interfaces. The output shows all the container IPs taking a long time, while other IPs resolve in milliseconds:

```
Tue Jul 03 16:27:46 GMT 2018 Resolving hostname for /172.19.0.1
Tue Jul 03 16:28:06 GMT 2018   ---> 172.19.0.1
Tue Jul 03 16:28:06 GMT 2018 Resolving hostname for /172.18.0.1
Tue Jul 03 16:28:25 GMT 2018   ---> 172.18.0.1
Tue Jul 03 16:28:25 GMT 2018 Resolving hostname for /172.19.1.1
Tue Jul 03 16:28:44 GMT 2018   ---> 172.19.1.1
Tue Jul 03 16:28:44 GMT 2018 Resolving hostname for /172.17.0.1
Tue Jul 03 16:29:03 GMT 2018   ---> 172.17.0.1
Tue Jul 03 16:29:26 GMT 2018 Resolving hostname for /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo
Tue Jul 03 16:29:26 GMT 2018   ---> localhost
Tue Jul 03 16:29:26 GMT 2018 Resolving hostname for /127.0.0.1
Tue Jul 03 16:29:26 GMT 2018   ---> localhost
```

We are running 2 docker networks (in addition to the standard docker networks that get created), both in bridge mode and with slightly different subnets:

```
    "Name": "cache_network",
    "Id": "222e5e722432993bd21fb767e76ee01d8d5b7c135dd6150c4801ee46df396ae3",
    "Created": "2018-06-04T08:31:09.52399079-06:00",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": {},
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.19.1.0/25",
                "Gateway": "172.19.1.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": true,
    "Ingress": false,
```

and

```
    "Name": "app_network",
    "Id": "f1f304db94ace6495e6db8b8c9e79b8fc5638c40461f3677572b9728d1fea1bc",
    "Created": "2018-06-04T08:31:09.35800211-06:00",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": {},
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/25",
                "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": true,
    "Ingress": false,
```

Worth noting that the problem occurs both locally using Docker, as well as in our Kubernetes environment. I'm hoping it's something silly with our docker network setup or ignite configs since all other apps on the host machine work fine.

Comment: I found a similar issue on GitHub: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31960 Try applying a proposed workaround. In general it's recommended to run Ignite Docker containers with "host" network driver to avoid network-related performance issues.

Comment: Also, you can try to add the following system property: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true.

Comment: @Denis Thanks for the link. Not sure it applies in my case as container -> container DNS is fast, the issue is with host machine -> container.

Comment: @RomanGuseinov Yeah, I had tried that previously with no luck, problem occurs when using IPv4 or IPv6 addresses.

Comment: @Mike, I tried to reproduce this locally but without success. It does not look the issue is related to Apache Ignite. Probably it is related to a host firewall.

Comment: @RomanGuseinov Thanks, it does appear to be something with my RHEL7 system as some of my colleagues don't have the same issue. I was able to work around it by adding /etc/hosts entries that map my docker network IPs back to themselves, i.e.:

    172.19.0.1 172.19.0.1

This forces the DNS resolution to return instantly.